# Concurrent Modification Exception while using FileWriter

Tags: java, exception, ioexception, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am trying to create 4 index files using FileWriter. However this code throws Concurrent Modification Exception. I searched a few forums and found the use of finally as a solution, which dint work. Please tell me where can the error be.

```
    public synchronized void writeToDisk() throws IndexerException {
    // TODO Implement this method
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        //System.out.println("entering writeToDisk");
        File file = new File("/Users/workspace/master/tmp//Index.txt");
        if(IndexAuthor==-1){
        file = new File("/Users/workspace/master/tmp/Author.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        }

        if(IndexTerm==-1){
            file = new File("/Users/workspace/master/tmp/Term.txt");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            }
        if(IndexCategory==-1){
            file = new File("/Users/workspace/master/tmp/Category.txt");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            }
        if(IndexLink==-1){
         file = new File("/Users/workspace/master/tmp/Link.txt");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(PostingsList.toString()); 
        //bw.close();
        //System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //do nothing
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if (bw == null)
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the exception stacktrace please

Comment: And please don't use tabs in Stack Overflow - they really don't work nicely, so your indentation is all messed up.

Comment: also change "if (bw == null)" inside finally block to "if (bw != null)", else you will get NullPointerException

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(Unknown Source)
 at edu.buffalo.cse.ir.wikiindexer.indexer.IndexWriter.writeToDisk(IndexWriter.java:239)
 at edu.buffalo.cse.ir.wikiindexer.SingleIndexerRunner$RunnerThread.run(SingleIndexerRunner.java:137)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I also changed "if(bw == null)" to "if(bw != null)".